# SQL Query for Find and Replace is not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

i want to run a find and replace query in my sql database using php my admin. The problem is that in the text that i want to find and replace are some " characters and this causes problems when i run the command...

i want to search for `align="right">` and replace it by `align="left">`

i did run this command but its not working:

```
UPDATE `ps_product_lang` SET `description` = replace(`description`,"align="right">","align="left">");
```

So im wondering how should this query look like as there are " characters? How is it possible to search for even much longer text and replace it using sql queries?

many thanks

Answer (score 2):

The replacement strings should be single-quoted as string literals:

```
UPDATE `ps_product_lang` SET `description` = replace(`description`, 'align="right">', 'align="left">');
```

Note that this solution is only useful if you are certain that all the strings in your `description` column are exactly `align="right">`. You will need to do additional work if, for example, you have some single-quoted attributes like `align='right'>`
in addition to the double-quoted attribute as above.

Also, if this is HTML markup you are performing replacements on, it is entirely possible that the closing `>` won't occur right after the `align` attribute.  In that case, you would really need to load each row into an HTML parser to change the attribute.

Comment: Your code was working perfect. I did also run it with the single quotes and saw that also some products where modified with this query. Thank you very much.

Comment: @user1786439 Happy to help. If the answer is sufficient, please mark it as accepted by clicking the tickmark beside it. Welcome to Stack Overflow.